# IONIC 2 Hide and Show textbox when ion-select is change

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I want to hide and show the textbox when the ion-select(combobox) is change

For example I have : 1 and 2 in ion-select
If i choose 1 the textbox will hide and if i choose 2 the textbox will appear

Here is my current code:

.ts

```
onChange(membership){
   if (this.membership = '1'){
   this.value = 1; }
       else if (this.membership = '2'){
      this.value = ""; }
 }
```

HTML

```
<ion-list>
<ion-item>
<ion-label>Register as</ion-label>
<ion-select [(ngModel)]="membership" (ionChange)="onChange(membership)">
  <ion-option value="1">member</ion-option>
 <ion-option value="2">nonmember</ion-option>
</ion-select>
</ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

this is the textbox that i want to hide

```
<ion-item [hidden]="!value">
<ion-label floating>Email Address</ion-label>
<ion-input type="text" name="email"  ></ion-input>
</ion-item>
```

When I'm opening the application the textbox is hiding and when i select from the combobox the textbox is showing but when I select the other item in the combobox its not hiding anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is just a simple error in `onChange` method. You are assigning the value with `=`, so it always returns true and set `this.value` to 1. You have to use double equals to verify equality :

```
onChange(membership){
    if (this.membership == '1') {
      this.value = 1; 
    } else if (this.membership == '2'){
      this.value = 0; 
    }
}
```